# Change appearance of flashing boxes around selected code elements when clicked in Pycharm

Tags: pycharm, editor, material-ui, appearance

In Pycharm whenever I click on any part of the code it highlights what was clicked on by putting a flashing white box around it. This makes it really annoying when typing in any sort of braces because I have trouble seeing where the caret is.

What I am talking about looks something like this:

[image]

I've been looking through SO, Google, and through the Pycharm settings and can't seem to find a way to change this behavior. Where can I find this setting? I'd like to remove the borders around the selected code elements and maybe instead use a translucent box with no borders.

I am using Pycharm 2019.2 with the Material Theme UI plugin version 4.3.2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your PyCharm Settings (Ctrl + Alt + S) go to Editor > Color Scheme > General  tab, where under the `code` category selected `Matched brace` on the right side, uncheck the Effects checkbox

[image]